# How to define a variable that is undefined?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
if (!config.callers[uID].calls) {
    console.log(config.callers[uID].calls);
    config.callers[uID].calls = 0;
    saveConfig();
    console.log(config.callers[uID].calls);
}
```

Where I have a JSON file that is called `config`, and has a property `callers` which is a collection of user IDs, and each one has a property `calls`. `saveConfig()` is a function that saves the config file.

As you can see, I am checking if the `calls` property is undefined, and if true then it defines it at 0. I also tried defining it to different stuff but it didn't seem to work. It just stays `undefined`.

Comment: I see checking for null not undefined

Comment: How does `saveConfig()` look like and how do you load the file in the first place?

Comment: `!config.callers[uID].calls || config.callers[uID].calls == null` the second part gets never evaluated for falsy values of the first, including `null`. what is the check for?

Comment: `null` is falsy, so the second part of your OR operator is useless.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I removed checking the null part, I thought it does matter in some cases.
SaveConfig():

```fs.writeFileSync("./config.json", JSON.stringify(config), (a) => {
  (a) ? console.log("error writing save to config.json:\n" + a) : ""
 })```

Comment: after the edit, what does actually nor work?

Comment: @Seblor I don't seem to understand, can you elaborate?

Comment: @NinaScholz it doesn't change the variable from undefined to 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
if(!config.callers.hasOwnProperty("uID")) {
    console.log(config.callers);
    config.callers[uID] = {};
    config.callers[uID].calls = 0;
    saveConfig();
    console.log(config.callers[uID].calls);
} else if(!config.callers[uID].hasOwnProperty("calls")) {
    console.log(config.callers[uID]);
    config.callers[uID].calls = 0;
    saveConfig();
    console.log(config.callers[uID].calls);
}
```

Comment: Haven't thought of using `hasOwnProperty()`, thank you!